# Cannot connect to remote AzureDB server via SSH Tunnel

Tags: ssh, azure-sql-database, remote-access, sqlcmd, ssh-tunnel

I want to connect to a remote AzureDB server (which has ip address **ip2** and hostname "**abc**.database.windows.net" ) from my local computer(which has ip address **ip1**). However, my local host can't directly access to DB server, so I had to use SSH Tunnel via a jump server (which has **ip3** and able to access to AzureDB server) for connecting. Here is what i was doing:

1, Create SSH Tunnel:

```
ssh -v -g -N -C -L local-port:**ip2**:1433 ssh-user@**ip3** -p 22
```

2, Connect to to DB server

```
sqlcmd -S 127.0.0.1,local-port -U db-user@**abc**.database.windows.net -P password -d db-name
```

But i got the error:

> Cannot open server '**abc**' requested by the login. Client with IP
>   address '**ip1**' is not allowed to access the server. To enable
>   access, use the Windows Azure Management Portal or run
>   sp_set_firewall_rule on the master database to create a firewall rule
>   for this IP address or address range. It may take up to five minutes
>   for this change to take effect.

I checked the tunnel connection with telnet and no error has been showed up. Can anyone tell me what's wrong with my work?

Answer (score 1):

If we want to access the remote Azure SQL database, make sure you have add the local IP '**ip1**' to the [Azure SQL Server firewall](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-server-level-firewall-rule) on Portal:

[image]

Please try bellow command:

```
ssh -L local_port:abc.database.windows.net:1433 db-user@abc.database.windows.net

sqlcmd -S 127.0.0.1,local-port -U db-user@**abc**.database.windows.net -P password -d db-name
```

Also reference this blogs:

1. [Unable to reach SQL database through SSH tunnel using sqlcmd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47092890/unable-to-reach-sql-database-through-ssh-tunnel-using-sqlcmd)
2. [Configuring SSH Tunnels for Database Connections](https://www.razorsql.com/articles/configuring_ssh_tunnels_database_connections.html)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Since I couldn't directly access to DB server for security reasons, I need to use a jump server (azure cloudapp server) for tunneling. The 1st reference is a little diffirent from my case, as in error log my ip1 is shown up, not 127.0.0.1. Even a jump server is used, does my ip1 need to be added to Azure SQL Server firewall? DB Server need to be set up to allow SSH connections?